# Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am using ubuntu 16.04

```
Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:31.527Z'
System info: host: 'supranimbus-Inspiron-3250', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-40-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
    at facedoxmain.FaceDox.InvokeBrowser(FaceDox.java:17)
    at facedoxmain.FaceDox.main(FaceDox.java:57)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:20033/hub/status] to be available after 45005 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:129)
```

Comment: Please share code too

Comment: 45 seconds is far too short as a Firefox timeout startup. More like ten minutes in my experience ;-{

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","home\\supranimbus\\downloads\\geckodriver");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
   System.out.println("browser openned");
   driver.get("https://192.168.0.29:3008/login/29");

Comment: @EJP Sir, we (Firefox) have evolved with availability of `Firefox Quantum`, 10 secs is what we need to load a complete webpage in an ideal `Test Bed`

Comment: Check this QA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374301/java-selenium-failing-to-open-web-page-on-firefox/45374991#45374991

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced this issue and finally found the answer. I had been referencing the Marionette driver which is no longer correct for FF version 53 and up on Selenium 3.5 or higher. The [GeckoDriver documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#usage) displays how the system property should be referenced.

I changed my code from:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "path");
```

to:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "path");
```

and now my local Firefox works perfectly.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Please, can you tell what is System.getProperty("user.dir") ? user.dir where or what is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haved this error for 2 days in WIndows, the solution for me was in Set.Plataform put Plataform.ANY or Plataform.Windows because Plataform.WIN10 not worked, marionette wasn't necessary and I added and neether works, only works this. I hope this helps someone else:

```
public class Main {
    public static RemoteWebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Lib/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
        desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.19.182:5557/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("execute automation");
        driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        driver.close();
        // write your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use implicit wait before get method, it will wait for the page to load  eg:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  this is also cannot work

Comment: please check the IP address you are passing, it is showing the site can't be reached took too long to respond