# Selenium Web Driver Mozilla Only Open

Tags: java, selenium

I started to learn SeleniumWeb driver with Java and I write some code like this :

```
package firstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class firstScript {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http//:www.google.com");
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
                element.sendKeys("mysql excel 2013");
                element.submit();
    }  
 }
```

If I run this code, mozilla only start, It is not contiune. I want to it to "google" and search "mysql excell 2013". How can I do?

Comment: your code looks fine. Should work. Are you getting any errors??

Comment: add wait just after driver get

Comment: I tried with chrome and its working fine.
Just need put Thread.sleep(3) after navigate to specific URL.

Comment: @Hiten in Chrome my code works fine but mozilla doesn't.

Comment: Okay.
I will check for mozilla too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NullPointerException failing to open web page on firefox through Java Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374301/java-lang-nullpointerexception-failing-to-open-web-page-on-firefox-through-java)

Comment: try `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");` and see if it works or not? btw what firefox version r u using?

Comment: Typically if the browser opens but doesn't respond to further commands it means that your browser version and driver version aren't compatible. I would suggest that you update FF to current and then grab the current FF Selenium driver and use it.

Answer (score -1):

I am using the **selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar** in which this code is not working but when I changed jar from 3.5.3 to **2.44.0** then Its working fine.

Its opening the firefox and search the "mysql excel 2013" and got the results of it.

So you need to change the selenium version or need to change the browser from firefox to chrome.