# Selenium with java issue using webdriver.firefox.marionette

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
package main_files;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class main_downloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\JavaPackage\\packages\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.wait(1);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

idk why, but for some reason this not working !, when I try to run it it just opens a Firefox window and do nothing !, even the search bar "which is supposed to recognize that I'm using a bot and change it's theme" is not doing that, could anyone tell me what's the exact problem please?!, Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) no more uses the *key* `webdriver.firefox.marionette` and instead of that you need to use `webdriver.gecko.driver`. Effectively, you need to replace the line:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\JavaPackage\\packages\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
```

with:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\JavaPackage\\packages\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevent detailed discussions in:

- [UnreachableBrowserException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException when “webdriver.firefox.marionette” is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374301/unreachablebrowserexception-caused-by-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-webd/45374991#45374991)
- [Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453)

Comment: it didn't work
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
console.error: SearchCache: "_readCacheFile: Error reading cache file:" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
1597445201342 Marionette INFO Listening on port 22663
Aug 15, 2020 1:46:41 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at main_files.main_downloader.main(main_downloader.java:10)"

Comment: but at least it gave me an error this time "and firefox recognizes that i'm using a bot" :)

Comment: @AMZ If you have seen the logs as _INFO: Detected dialect: W3C_, this effectively means [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated [tag:firefox] _Browsing Context_ was successfully initialized. For the following error `IllegalMonitorStateException` can you raise a new question please?

Comment: Accepted !, but I have to wait 90 min to ask again :/

Comment: Don't worry, contributors are pretty much regular within Selenium tag. Happy learning.